# Text parsing in Windows Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I need to monitor services of my pc using batch file and a .txt file where the list of services are contained.

```
For /f "delims= " %%a in (list.txt) do (
    Set %%a=%serviceName%
)

Set errorlevel=0

Sc query "%serviceName%" | FIND "STATE" | FINDSTR /i "RUNNING"

If errorlevel 1 (
    Echo %serviceName% stopped
) else (
    Echo %serviceName% running
)
```

Please help?

Comment: What is `%count%` for? It doesn't seem to do anything. Also, it gets reset to 0 every time the loop iterates.

Comment: Thank you! yes, I already removed it but it still doesnt work

Comment: `Set errorlevel=0` sets an ordinary variable named `errorlevel`. The ordinary environment is examined first by `if %errorlevel% ...` - and the user-set value overrides the system-set value. `if errorlevel ...` examines the system-set errorlevel. Setting "magic variables" (pseudovariables maintained by the system like `errorlevel`, `date`, `time` etc. is a minefield.

Comment: `"delims= "` in a `for/f` command means that the delimiter is set **only** to spaces; its default is separators like spaces and commas. `"delims="` where there is no space between the `=` and the `"` directs "no delimiters" so the entire line from the input, including spaces, will be assigned to the metavariable `%%a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%%a` is the value of that iteration of the `for` loop, and `%serviceName%` is the value of the serviceName variable, so unless list.txt is a list of variable names, you're setting one value to another value instead of setting an actual variable.

Ordinarily, your set statement should look like `set serviceName=%%a`. However, you can move your close parentheses to the bottom of the script to get rid of the need for the variable altogether. Also, the default delimiter is already a space, so you can also get rid of that bit. The `errorlevel` variable is an existing system variable, and it's generally a bad idea to set it manually.

```
for /f %%a in (list.txt) do (
    sc query "%%a"|find "STATE"|findstr /i "RUNNING"

    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo %%a stopped
    ) else (
        echo %%a running
    )
)
```